# How do I use fonts from TeX Live in Graphviz?

Tags: fonts, graphs, computer-modern

So I need to set my fonts for `dot` the way the `pt` to be the same as in `pdflatex` - so I'm looking for a way to use the same fonts `pdflatex` uses. Note also, that I'm unsure whether `cm-super` or `cm-unicode` (or `cm-lgc`?) is used (what is the way to get that known, BTW?). Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I found a way to install TeX Live's fonts as system ones (It's all happening on Windows and involves getting `.afm` files, then copying to their place `.pfb` files and then using program *AfmToPfm* from http://www.proximasoftware.com).

Now the remaining part remains - how do I know which font gets used? (I know uninteresting answer involving viewing file properties with `pdffonts` or PDF viewer's "Properties" dialog, but are there other solutions?)

Comment: I actually reconsidered the thoughts that brought me to the question and answer appeared to be not so fruitful as it could be (for me), so if nobody is interested, I'll delete it after a while.

Comment: Easier would be to use Latin Modern and install the opentype versions system-wide. `pdflatex` will use the type1 versions. (If you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you can use the opentype for both, of course.) Which fonts are being used depends on your source. Without knowing what code you are compiling, it is impossible to say which fonts you are using. By default, Computer Modern is used in metafont format. If you use `fontenc`, you'll get the type1 versions if they are installed (e.g. `cm-super`). If you load font packages, they will obviously change what is used.